# Failed to get matching snapshot: Lost connection to the application

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, xcuitest, aws-device-farm

I'm starting with AWS DeviceFarm and trying to integrate it into my CI pipeline. Recently, when I run my app tests on my device poll, I'm getting the error

`Failed to get matching snapshot: Lost connection to the application (pid 402). (Underlying Error: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again. The connection to service on pid 0 created from an endpoint was invalidated.)`

This error always happens on specific devices: on the **iPad Air 2 with iOS 13.6** and on the **iPhone 11 Pro Max with iOS 13.1.3**.

I tested it locally using simulators of those same versions and I didn't get any errors. It looks like something from the environment to me.

Can anyone confirm if the problem is with the environment or how can I solve it?

I'm using XCUITest and Swift to write my UI tests

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I am an engineer on the AWS Device Farm team. Do you mind providing me with a run url so I can take a look at your test execution?

For better assistance, I suggest utilizing the AWS Device Farm forums as a medium to contact members of the the service team like myself: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193

Andy

Comment: Thank you Andy! I did it :) https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=339411